# Query nested json using jq

Tags: json, shell, nested, jq

I have the json file `about.json` as below

```
{
  "build": {
    "tag": "189",
    "buildtime": "2019-07-19-08-05"
  },
  "microservices": [
    {
      "appId": "builds",
      "imageName": "build-server:8",
      "volumesFrom": []
    },
    {
      "appId": "studio",
      "imageName": "tci-webserver:4074",
      "volumesFrom": [
        "tci-download-studio:xxx"
      ]
    },
    {
      "appId": "site",
      "imageName": "site:22",
      "volumesFrom": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to substitute value for volumesFrom for for example for first appId: "builds", but I am not able to fetch the key in the first place.
Could anyone help me with the command to do this.

I have the value stored in volumes variable. I want to assign this variable as a value to volumesFrom key for first appId:builds.

I tried accessing the volumesFrom object using syntax such as

```
jq .microservices.volumesFrom about.json
```

```
jq .microservices.[0].volumesfrom
```

But none seems to fetch the key which I am expecting.

Comment: @k0pernikus could you please help?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.  Parts of your question are vague, and your comments seem to indicate you're changing the question.  If you provide all the inputs (not just the JSON file), and the expected output, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the microservice object of interest:

```
.microservices[] | select(.appId == "builds")
```

Then with that, you could then update the `volumesFrom` value:

```
(.microservices[] | select(.appId == "builds")).volumesFrom = ...
```

https://jqplay.org/s/zLsEYAQrFC

Comment: Can I not hardcode the "builds" and write something generic so that it applies to any appId of the json ?

Comment: Well you'll want to pass that in as an argument and substitute in that value using `--arg` or `--argjson`

Comment: I have variable vols as ["a":1,"b":2]. I write this query 
`jq -r --arg volumesFrom $vols about.json '(.microservices[1] | select(.volumesFrom == $volumesFrom))'` But it doesnt seem to work

Comment: My json file name is x.json, now when I fire the query as suggested above, I do not get the results as expected:   ```jq .microservices[]  x.json | select(.appId == 'builds')``` The `Error` message is ```bash: syntax error near unexpected token `.microservices[]'```